# How to fill regions with the spplot function and RColorBrewer

Tags: r, maps, geospatial, r-sp

I have data file, with two columns, Column1-States; Column2-Saturation(%). 
Using package sp and RColorBrewer; To make map,  i download gadm - level1 india.
But i am not able to put percentage in Indian regions, how can i do that,please check my R- code
The code is shown below

```
ind1 = readRDS("IND_adm1.rds")
spplot(ind1, "NAME_1", scales=list(draw=T), colorkey=F, main="India")
ind1$NAME_1 = as.factor(ind1$NAME_1)
ind1$adhaar = runif(length(ind1$NAME_1))
spplot(ind1,"NAME_1",  col.regions=rgb(0,ind1$adhaar, 0), colorkey=T, 
       main="Indian States")
```

Answer (score 2):

I modified your code. You want to use `adhaar` in order to fill Indian regions. Seeing the OP's comment, `adhaar` seems to be a data file. In order to draw the following graphic, we need a column containing saturation values in the position of `adhaar` in the `spplot()` part below.

```
library(sp)
library(raster)
library(RColorBrewer)

ind1 <- getData("GADM", country = "india", level = 1)

set.seed(111)
ind1$NAME_1 <- as.factor(ind1$NAME_1)
ind1$adhaar <- runif(length(ind1$NAME_1))

spplot(ind1, "adhaar",
      colorkey = list(space = "bottom"), scales = list(draw = TRUE),
      main = "India")
```

[image]

If you want to use `RColorBrewer` and try to reflect Saturation, which I assume is `adhaar`, you can use `cuts` and `col.region`. You need to think how you wanna set up `cuts`. This part is up to you. If you want to receive a help, you want to provide a minimal reproducible data as well as your code. Otherwise, it is hard for everyone here to help you out. Anyway, I hope this give you some ideas of what you wanna do for your task.

```
spplot(ind1, "adhaar",
      colorkey = list(space = "bottom"), scales = list(draw = TRUE),
      main = "India", cuts = 5,
      col.regions = brewer.pal(6, "Greens"))
```

[image]

Comment: i want saturation rate to be shown in regions, the color which comes here is random color, it do not depict higher and lower..

Comment: Data file is adhaar, whereas, saturation is percentage column, which i wish to use.. also send me you email id jazzurro....

Comment: @imrankhan Just a note. If you are done, please click a green tick which is just under the up/down vote triangles. You have not ticked it for all questions that you have asked before.

Comment: @imrankhan Then, you need to properly present your data. Otherwise, SO users have no idea of what you are trying to do. At least, what I can guess is that you want to use the column for saturation in the position where I have `adhaar`.